# Overflowing stack with huge local variable?

Tags: c, linux

As it is said that 8 mb of stack is given to each process.
This stack will be used to store local variables.
So if i take an array of size max than of the stack , it must overflow ??

```
 int main()
{
int arr[88388608];
int arr1[88388608];
int arr2[88388608];
while(1);
return 0;
}
```

But i am unable to get the result !

Comment: When you overflow the stack you get *undefined behavior* which can sometimes seem to work as expected. Also, compilers these days are pretty smart. Since those arrays are unused why should the compiler actually create space for them?

Comment: What happens when you change the type of arr from `int` to `volatile int`?

Comment: Also, AFAIK, the size of the stack can vary on different systems.

Comment: 8 MB also is a lot of stack. I wouldn't rely upon having that much.

Comment: Try to put `arr2[88388607] = 0;` in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the world of optimizing compilers!

Because of the as-if rule, the compiler is only required to build something that would have same observable results as your original code.
So the compiler if free to:

- remove the unused arrays
- remove the empty loop
- store the dynamic arrays from main outside of the stack - because main is a special function that shall be called only once by the environment

If you want to observe the stack overflow (the bad one, not our nice site :-) ),
you should:

- use some code to fill the arrays
- compile with all optimization removed and preferently in debug mode to tell the compiler *do what I wrote as accurately as you can*

The following code does SIGSEGV with CLang 3.4.1 when compiled as `cc -g foo.c -o foo`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 88388608

void fill(int *arr, size_t size, int val) {
    for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++) {
        arr[i] = val;
    }
}    
int main() {
    int arr[SIZE];
    int arr1[SIZE];
    int arr2[SIZE];

    fill(arr, SIZE, 0);
    fill(arr1, SIZE, 0);
    fill(arr2, SIZE, 0);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", arr[12], arr1[15], arr2[18]);

    return 0;
}
```

and even this code works fine when compiled as `-O2` optimization level... Compilers are now too clever for me, and I'm not brave enough to thoroughly look at the assembly code which would be the only real way to understand what is actually executed!

Comment: @Lingxi: Your answer was almost correct. If you translate it to C and undelete it (and ping me in a comment) I will upvote it because mine is just an explaination around yours